# python 3.4 TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'generator'

Tags: python

This is my code passing some float values generated by a range function to plotter:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gK_inf = 20.70
gK_0 = 0.01
tauN = 0.915 + 0.037

def graph(formula, t_range):  
    t = np.array(t_range)  
    gK = formula(t)  # <- note now we're calling the function 'formula' with x
    plt.plot(t, gK)
    plt.xlabel(r"$g_K$")
    plt.ylabel(r"$\frac{P_{i}}{P_{o}}$")
    plt.legend([r"$\frac{P_{i}}{P_{o}}$"])
    annotation_string = r"$E=0$" 
    plt.text(0.97,0.8, annotation_string, bbox=dict(facecolor='red', alpha=0.5), 
         transform=plt.gca().transAxes, va = "top", ha="right")  
    plt.show()  

def my_formula(t):
    return np.power((np.power(gK_inf,0.25))*((np.power(gK_inf,0.25)-np.power(gK_0,0.25))*np.exp(-t/tauN)),4)

def frange(x, y, jump):
    while x < y:
        yield x
        x += jump

graph(my_formula, frange(0,11e-3,1e-3))
```

And this is the thrown error:

```
>  gK = formula(t)  # <- note now we're calling the function 'formula'
> with x
>       File "F:\Eclipse\my_test\gK", line 26, in my_formula
>         return np.power((np.power(gK_inf,0.25))*((np.power(gK_inf,0.25)-np.power(gK_0,0.25))*np.exp(-t/tauN)),4)
>     TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'generator'
```

May you help, please?

Comment: If you want a floating point range, use `numpy.arange` or maybe [`numpy.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `t_range` is a generator.  You try to convert this into a numpy array with `t = np.array(t_range)`.  But it doesn't work.  Calling `np.array` on a generator just returns a one-element array with the generator as its only element.  It doesn't unroll the generator.

You can try `np.fromiter(t_range, dtype=np.float)` instead.  Or just convert `t_range` to a list first.

Incidentally, it's unclear why you wrote `frange` at all, as it essentially does what the builtin `range` already does with its `step` argument.

Comment: I did as you said: using `np.fromiter(t_range)`, and now I have this error: `TypeError: Required argument 'dtype' (pos 2) not found`